# What does it mean "add a Copy Files phase" to add a Framework to a project

Tags: xcode, frameworks

I'm reading this answer about adding a plugin into xCode 3

```
Hi, I did a few things to correct (I do not know which steps solved the problem)
1) downloaded a fresh copy
2) linked link against the framework
3) added a copy phase to include the framework into the application
```

What does "**copy phase**" mean ?

I've solved by adding the framework to the MAC OSX Library, but I would like to add it to my project instead. I've been told how to add it in xCode4, but how to add it to xCode3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get to it from here [image] You want the copy files.

If you want to see an example of it - have a look at this [example Xcode Project](https://github.com/Abizern/CommitViewer) on GitHub which has a Copy Files phase to copy a Framework - and also some explanation in the Readme.

Comment: I'm actually using xCode3. Can you tell me where I can set it in the previous version ? I actually already see it in the Target information: http://cl.ly/AOzt

Comment: I've actually solved by copying the framework into the Library/Frameworks folder in mac osx. Is that the proper soution ?

Comment: That will work for you, but you need to do the same thing to the target computer when you distribute your app.

Comment: You mean ask all customers to do it for me ?

Comment: No - obviously. But since you're getting round the problem by directly adding it to your own Frameworks folder; I'm trying to tell you that it's not going to work for installation. I don't have Xcode3 so I can't tell you where the option is as I can't remember. But It may be an option if you right click on your target.