# How to add frameworks into the Swift project?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to add a library to my Swift project. I found 3 different places to add.
I want to know the correct way to do this and the purpose of each one.

### General tab

> select the target -> general

- Embed binaries
- Linked frameworks and libraries

### Build phase

> select the target -> build phase

- Embed frameworks
- link binary with libraries

### New copy file phase

> select the target -> click on + button -> select "New copy file phase"

- choose the destination as a framework
- select the framework

### Questions

1. When do I need to "Embed binaries" and "Linked frameworks and
   libraries"? and when do I need to do the build phase one?
2. Do I need to do multiple of these things to add a framework?
3. What is the difference between them?

Comment: Short & Good Explanation :https://stackoverflow.com/a/46644892/2323806

Answer (score 4):

1.Select the project file from the project navigator on the left side of the project window.

2.Select the target for where you want to add frameworks in the project settings editor.

3.Select the “Build Phases” tab, and click the small triangle next to “Link Binary With Libraries” to view all of the frameworks in your application.

4.To Add frameworks, click the “+” below the list of frameworks.

5.To select multiple frameworks, press and hold the command key while using the mouse to click the desired frameworks.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, You mean I need to do is adding it in build phase? and not "link binary with libraries"?

Comment: don't you see the option "link binary with libraries" in build phase :)

Comment: sorry I wrote incorrectly. I wanted to ask about "New copy file phase". Do I need to add this one?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539777/what-does-it-mean-add-a-copy-files-phase-to-add-a-framework-to-a-project here you can see this example

Comment: Yes it helped, Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

"Binary" means: compiled code — as opposed to "source code", which is what you are working with when you write code as text.

They could have given you source code and let you compile it, but they didn't; they are keeping the source code secret, so they've given it all to you after compilation, so that you can't read it.

"Embedded" means: to be included inside your app bundle, by copying them into it at build time.

So, they are handing you some compiled code (frameworks) and telling you how to include them inside your app bundle. These frameworks, unlike Cocoa's frameworks, do not already exist on the device, so if you don't include them inside the app, they won't be present and your app would be unable to call into them.

Contrast this to Cocoa's frameworks. They, too, are compiled code. But they do already exist on the device. Therefore they are not embedded inside your app; they are merely linked (and, if they appeared, would appear in the next group, Linked Frameworks and Libraries).
[What are Embedded Binaries in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30173529/what-are-embedded-binaries-in-xcode)