# Add Swift Package to a custom framework

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

Pretty new to creating frameworks with SPM dependencies. So I made a new framework project, added some of my classes/files as well as a SPM dependency (CocoaLumberjack logger). Framework compiles fine.

When I look for my framework product that I'm planning on embedding into some other project I see that it is in my Products folder. Alongside with it I see CocoaLumberjack module. Inside of my framework there is not much beside the exec file.

When I try to embed my framework into some other projects. Nothing compiles because it says that CocoaLumberjack module is missing.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Am I missing an important step or soemthing?

Comment: Did you list all the dependencies in your top level Package ?

Comment: no :( first time using SPM. Can you please provide some source where I can read about how to do so? thank you

Comment: oh, reading about it now, I'm not creating a package, I'm creating Framework, so I don't even see package.swift. Unless I'm getting confused here? @Mr.SwiftOak

Comment: Maybe there was some misunderstaning on my part. Never mind, I posted answer below with tutorial on creating SPM packages linking them into framework and using  framerork in your project. If you are not creating SPM package, but only using some 3rd party packages you can skip some steps in step 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, there are numerous isses you could have faced during importing framework itself. It also depends if you use framework as binary or source code. I assume you were using source code approach as you are the creator of framework. You can however check all approaches here: [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51151862/how-to-add-frameworks-into-the-swift-project) . Let's look at all the steps you need to implement in order to successfully use framework with SPM dependencies in your swift project.

1. create SPM properly and also link all additional SPM dependencies [tutorial here](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/managing-dependencies-using-the-swift-package-manager/). Make sure all your classes, structs etc. and their coresponding initializer has correct access level property. If you plan to use them outside of the package, use public initializers..
   2)Once you created you SPM package, link it to framework. For the sake of this answer I created `testFramework` and linked one of my custom SPM package called `VodApiPackage` . This package also contains dependency to another `BaseTvApiServicePackage`.

[image: screenshot1]

I also added `TestPrinter` file containing simple function for creating error declared in my SPM package. This function servers only for checking that everything is working properly and will be user later. It is also declared public.

```
import Foundation
import VodApiPackage

public struct TestPrinter {
public init () {}

public func makeTest() {
    let x = VodApiError.customErr(msg: "testMsg")
    print(x.localizedDescription)
}
```

}

2. Open your project and make link to framework, you can also check this [nice tutorial](https://programmingwithswift.com/create-a-swift-framework/). The most important step from tutorial is step 5 and 6. Where you drag `.xcproj` into your project and link libraries and framework
3. make sure your library and SPM dependencies are correctly linked in your project. Check sample project below.

[image: screenshot1]

4. Build and test using your framework and its packages:

   ```
   import UIKit
   import testFramework

   class ViewController: UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     testmodel()

    TestPrinter().makeTest()
    }
   }
   ```

Comment: I'm facing a new issue :( When I embed the framework into an app (drag&drop) all works fine but when I build the framework for distribution, it seems that it doesn't have all those dependencies :( Any idea?

Comment: what is does exactly error message say?

Comment: "Missing required modules ..." and basically lists the modules it needs. So what I see is that once I build the framework, inside the products folder there are all this modules and my framework .framework, but adding just my framework doesn't wok. So I assume it all should somehow be bundled together?

Comment: When you change scheme with "edit scheme" and try to build it for "release" configuration (which is same as making an archive) , does it build? Also when dealing with SPM there sometimes is need for deleting derived data and re-adding SPM package. This might also help. You can also copy whole framework folder into project and then linking .framework in the "frameworks, libraries and embedded content" section.