# Add dependencies to binary targets in Swift Package Manager

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager, xcframework

I want to create a Swift Package with binary targets which has sub dependencies. As the binary targets not support sub dependencies out of the box, I have created a wrapper target that depends on both the binary framework and other dependencies as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65255303/627667)

Package has a target called `Logger`.
`CocoaLumberjack` is a dependency of `Logger`.

`Logger` I have generated as XCFramwork and hosted in a server as publicly accessible. Below I have added a screenshot of the Xcode project which I used to generate XCFramwork.

Please refer to the Package manifest file.

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "spmpoc",
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "Logger",
            targets: ["LoggerTarget"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(
            name: "CocoaLumberjack",
            url: "https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack.git",
            from: "3.6.1"),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
              name: "LoggerTarget",
              dependencies: [.target(name: "LoggerWrapper",
                                     condition: .when(platforms: [.iOS]))]
            ),
        .target(
              name: "LoggerWrapper",
              dependencies: [
                .target(name: "Logger", condition: .when(platforms: [.iOS])),
                .product(name: "CocoaLumberjack", package: "CocoaLumberjack")
              ]
            ),
        .binaryTarget(name: "Logger", url: "https://mypath.com/Logger.xcframework.zip", checksum: "mychecksum")
    ]
)
```

I am able to add Swift package via Swift Package Manager, but When I try to import `Logger` module build error occured as `..../Logger.framework/Modules/Logger.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftinterface:4:8: No such module 'CocoaLumberjack'`

Could someone please help me to figure out what could be the issue here?

Error
[image]

XCFramwork code snapshot for reference
[image]

***Update:***

I have change import to @_implementationOnly import in Logger.swift. Now in the generated .swiftinterface files does not contains the "import CocoaLumberjack" hence, compile error went away. However, app crashing because it is still looking for CocoaLumberjack.framework but its not available. `'.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestSPMApp-gfbagjtzjrrkjuathrrienvklwxs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CocoaLumberjack.framework/CocoaLumberjack' (no such file)`
CocoaLumberJack added to Logger framework as a pod dependency. It seems, inside the Pods-Logger.xcconfig file it is referring to CocoaLumberjack.framework. I believe this causes the issue now.

[image]

Comment: try this [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71585267/14559220)

Comment: @Mr.SwiftOak Thanks for the input. I had went through the answer and I re-look in to my XCFramwork generation project as well. It seems frameworkes linked correctly there. I had updated my question with XCframework part as well.

Comment: Try also checking if it is not problem with arm64 simulator , as [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/655599)

Comment: In debug mode it has set to Build Active Architecture Only. I tried to build with real device as well, same issue there. I am really not sure if this is due to some misconfiguration in Package.swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the real issue here is that the dependencies don't need to be a part of your modules's public interface. You would need to replace all instances of `import` for the dependencies in your code to `@_implementationOnly import`

E.g.

`@_implementationOnly import CocoaLumberjack`

You can read more about `@_implementationOnly` [here](https://forums.swift.org/t/update-on-implementation-only-imports/26996)

Comment: Though compilation error went away, now app crashing because it is still looking for CocoaLumberjack.framework but its not available. Any idea? '.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestSPMApp-gfbagjtzjrrkjuathrrienvklwxs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CocoaLumberjack.framework/CocoaLumberjack' (no such file),

Comment: CocoaLumberJack added to Logger framework  as a pod dependency. It seems, inside the Pods-Logger.xcconfig file it is refering to CocoaLumberjack.framework. I believe this causes the issue now. FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/CocoaLumberjack"
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = $(inherited) COCOAPODS=1
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack.framework/Headers"

Comment: I think so too, because it works perfectly if I have the dependency added through SPM in the main framework target

Comment: I also tried removing Pods-Logger.framework from the Link Binary Libraries of main project. And then generated the Xcframework. Issue still persists. Not sure from where these linker headers coming from :(

Comment: I am having exact same issue. Do you have any idea how to resolve this problem?

Comment: @smartsanja Are you able to archive the framework after deintegrating cocoapods? I am getting 'no such module XXX' in every place where I am importing the dependency.

Comment: I got it to work - see my answear https://stackoverflow.com/a/71966236/6396909

Comment: @michalbanan I still could not resolve the issue. In your approach "added SQLite.swift via SPM" that means you added SQLite via SPM in your main target and then generate the XCframework?

Comment: @smartsanja yes, using spm  instead of cocoapods for your main target works perfectly.

Comment: @smartsanja exactly, you need to use SPM instead of cocoapods to archive your framework

Comment: Yeah, I had try with SPM all working fine. But I'm wondering with Cocoapods is it really not possible? I could not found any official statement or such, saying it is not possible. Do you guys have any idea on that?

Comment: I have accepted this answer even though this is not exact solution. I am still looking for a solution to use cocoapods in the main project and then generate XCframwork