# Supporting 3rd party dependencies for binaryTarget via SPM

Tags: swift, cocoapods, swift-package-manager

I am having a problem migrating my framework from cocoapods to SPM (Swift Package Manager).
Framework is actually dependent on `SQLite.swift` library via cocoapods.

The framework itself is precompiled as a xcframework like:

```
xcodebuild archive \
 -workspace ${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.xcworkspace \
 -scheme ${SCHEME} \
 -archivePath ${SIMULATOR_ARCHIVE_PATH} \
 -sdk iphonesimulator \
 -destination "generic/platform=iOS Simulator" \
 SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
 BUILD_LIBRARIES_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES \
 DEFINES_MODULE=YES \
 | xcpretty

 xcodebuild archive \
 -workspace ${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.xcworkspace \
 -scheme ${SCHEME} \
 -archivePath ${IOS_DEVICE_ARCHIVE_PATH} \
 -destination "generic/platform=iOS" \
 -sdk iphoneos \
 SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
 BUILD_LIBRARIES_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES \
 DEFINES_MODULE=YES \
 | xcpretty

 xcodebuild -create-xcframework \
 -framework ${SIMULATOR_ARCHIVE_PATH}/Products/Library/Frameworks/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework \
 -framework ${IOS_DEVICE_ARCHIVE_PATH}/Products/Library/Frameworks/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework \
 -output ${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.xcframework \
 | xcpretty
```

Now i want to make it possible to distribute framework via SPM but unfortunately can't make it happen.

Looking into the internet I found out that my case is fairly similar to the one firebase had with `FirebaseAnalytics` so I came up with the same approach with my `Package.swift` manifest file and created wrapper target:

```
let package = Package(
    name: "REDACTED",
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "REDACTED",
            targets: ["REDACTEDSPMTarget"]
        ),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(name: "SQLite.swift", url: "https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift.git", from: "0.13.3")
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "REDACTEDSPMTarget",
            dependencies: [
                .target(name: "REDACTEDSPMWrapper", condition: .when(platforms: [.iOS])),
            ],
            path: "SwiftPM-PlatformExclude/REDACTEDSPMTarget"
        ),
        .target(
            name: "REDACTEDSPMWrapper",
            dependencies: [
                .target(name: "REDACTED", condition: .when(platforms: [.iOS])),
                .product(name: "SQLite", package: "SQLite.swift")
            ],
            path: "REDACTEDSPMWrapper"
        ),
        .binaryTarget(
            name: "REDACTED",
            path: "Framework/REDACTED.xcframework"
        ),
    ]
)
```

Unfortunately i can't make it work when trying to add the package locally via SPM. The project builds just fine but the app can't start due to the error:

```
Library not loaded: @rpath/SQLite.framework/SQLite
Reason: tried: '{...}/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SQLite.framework/SQLite' (no such file)
```

It looks like at some point compiler is not linking `SQLite.framework` file. I think cocoapods does that using one of the *Build phase* script file.

What may be the case here?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow i did make it to work...

- removed cocoapods using `pod deintegrate`
- added `SQLite.swift` via SPM
- added `@_implementationOnly import` for every `SQLite` reference in framework's target
- archived using slighty different parameters:

```
xcodebuild archive \
  -scheme ${SCHEME} \
 -archivePath ${SIMULATOR_ARCHIVE_PATH} \
 -sdk iphonesimulator \
 -destination "generic/platform=iOS Simulator" \
 SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
 BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES \
 DEFINES_MODULE=YES \
 | xcpretty
```

Framework works now as expected, without crashing. Only one thing left to take care of is that the dependency is added to both framework as well as to the app itselt causing:

```
Class _TtC6SQLite6Backup is implemented in both
.../demo.app/Frameworks/REDACTED.framework/REDACTED 
and 
.../spmdemo.app/spmdemo. 
One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

Comment: Hi ... I was wondering if you found a fix for the 2nd issue you mentioned here (Class is implemented in both framework and app)